# Get packet in a raw form with netfilter

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming, netfilter

I want to encapsulate all the traffic in UDP. I can capture it already and send forward. But now I want to do encapsulation. For this task I need to get full packet in a raw form. But how can I do this? My code is

```
while ((rv = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)))
{
        printf("pkt received\n");
        nfq_handle_packet(h, buf, rv);
}
```

Should I do this in my callback? If so, then how? Or I can just set NF_DROP in my callback, and use *buf* and *rev* from *while* loop?
I only can find function from netfilter to get payload, dst, src etc, but not the packet in raw form. Or can I reinterpret somehow nfq_data to char*?

Comment: you will find here a Lightweight TCP/IP library, there is an interesting documentation in rawapi.txt in the doc folder, i think it will help you, i don't know witch raw tcp/ip library you use. link: http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will indeed want to do this in your callback. You will want to call the nfq_get_payload, which will give you a pointer to the entire contents of the packet including the IP and UDP headers. Depending on how you will be encapsulating the packet, you can call nfq_set_verdict with a pointer to the new packet data or drop the packet with NF_DROP and then reinject the newly encapsulated packet through a raw socket or something similar.

Comment: Thank you! I just thought that nfq_get_payload returns only payload (just ip packet payload without IP headers etc) but not the entire packet.


ps: sorry for offtopic, but do you have some useful links to libnetfilter manual? In my opinion official doxygen documentation is not fully informative.

Comment: I honestly get most of what I need from the Doxygen and libnetfilter_queue code itself. I haven't dealt with raw libnetfilter/libnetlink at all.